# Steps to recreate SQL Server Instance

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, disaster-recovery

I'm writing a disaster recovery protocol at work - a protocol that describes how to create a SQL Server instance from scratch in case that the PROD server will be unavailable.

We have SQL Server 2008 Enterprise.

We have a valid backup procedure but I want to have a document that will describes all the steps.

Do you know/encountered a link/s that specifies all the necessary steps to create a duplicate SQL Server based on an old server?

I need that it will be identical in all its components of the instance (I'm not talking about the installation of the Server / cluster)
I'm talking about components such as:

- Database
- Jobs
- Server configuration attributes (sp_configure)
- Security objects - Logins, Users, Permissions, Credentials and Audit configuration
- Other objects such as Linked servers, Mail profiles
- Replication information

The reason I'm looking for such thing is because:

1. I don't want to start with nothing. I guess that the basics are written somewhere online.
2. It's a good way to verify that I haven't forgotten anything.

An example for a nice post I've found regarding Logins, Users and permissions:
 http://johnsterrett.com/2012/01/24/8-steps-to-moving-database-users-from-sql-2005-to-sql-2008/

Thanks in advance,

Roni

Answer (score 1):

Most of those items, assuming they are static, you can script them out from SQL Management Studio. Easy enough to test as well. Setup an instance on a test server, run your SQL install and run the scripts that you created.